# Vue3 programmatic routing not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Programmatic routing doesn't seem to work as expected in Chrome (Version 88.0.4324.182). I have a simple app with a button to go back, forward or redirect to a page.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "vue-3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Programmatic routing:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    redirect() {
      return this.$router.push({ name: "About" });
    },
    back() {
      return this.$router.go(-1);
    },
    forward() {
      return this.$router.go(1);
    },
  },
};
```

`back()` will not go back one entry, after switching the routes. Firefox or Chrome in incognito mode behave as expected.

I made a sandbox to demonstrate the issue. Routing there works fine, as long as the app runs embedded in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-hoover-2jcpc

If you open the app directly in Chrome, it will probably not work: https://2jcpc.csb.app/

Can someone confirm this or is there a solution to this?

Comment: The app from the direct link works fine for me (Chrome 88 in macOS)

Comment: Even the "Go Back" button? Chrome 88 here as well and it doesn't respond at all.

Comment: Yes, all buttons seem to work for me.

Comment: Everything is working fine for me (Chrome Version 88.0.4324.182 on Ubuntu 20.04)